# Purpose and meaning of "dabei" in the sentence "sehen Sie dabei nicht ins Bildlexikon"?

Tags: german-to-english

What "dabei" is for in the "sehen Sie dabei nicht ins Bildlexikon" sentence?

And what is its meaning here?

Comment: Did you have a look into a dictionary? Which possible meanings did you find? Which question is still open? We don't want to compete with dictionaries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Presumably, there is a previous sentence like

> Lösen Sie die folgende Aufgabe/Lesen Sie den folgenden Text. Sehen Sie **dabei** nicht ins Bildlexikon

Dabei refers to the previous sentence. It can be translated as

> Read the following text. **While doing so**, do not look into the visual dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Those *hier*- and *da*-words are backreferencing adverbs made from a preposition.

> Er telefoniert **beim Fahren**.
>
> **Er fährt.** Er telefoniert **dabei**.

The preposition *bei* can take a nominalized infinitive. It's a description of a continous action happening during the action of the finite verb. **Dabei** serves the same purpose, but references a previous clause for the "backdrop" action.

> **Ergänzen Sie die fehlenden Wörter.** Sehen Sie **dabei** nicht ins Bildlexikon.

So, this *dabei* references another action in a previous clause. For example solving a problem.

> Sehen Sie **beim Ergänzen der fehlenden Wörter** nicht ins Bildlexikon.